# Mod_ReWrite / ReWriteMap a URL using a database lookup script

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite, rewritemap

**The Scenario**
I have completely rewritten an old existing ASP classic ecommerce website over to PHP.

The database design of the previous site had alot of relational ID problems causing troublesome linking of product data rows to other tables in the database.

To get around this I also redesigned the database, giving products new Primary Keys, whilst still keeping a column in the table with the products old PK.

**The Problem**
 
The problem I have is when the site is relaunched, I need all search engine links that used to point to 'Product.asp?ProductID=29' to lookup the the database, match the products old PK, and redirect to the products new PK i.e. 'Products.php?ID=53'.

I'm looking to do this with Mod_ReWrite/ReWriteMap, however, all documentation I can find online doesn't state how to deal with the database script PK lookup.

**Update**
I've read up further on Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams' suggestion at http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritemap > External Rewriting Program, and it seems to be correct and the ideal solution. 
However, after contacting my host, they do not enable `ReWriteMap` on their servers.

I've supplied my own, but by no means the best/correct solution of achieving this without `ReWriteMap` enabled.

Comment: Can't you not operate that magic using a genuine Product.asp page? Otherwise, you could redirect Products.asp to ProductRedirect.php or something like that to the same effect.

Comment: I was considering something like this, however, from my knowledge, first i would need mod_rewrite to accept the .asp file extension, redirect to a php database lookup script, and then use a 301 redirect to the final page. I'm unsure whether Google etc. will be happy with all the redirection, or if it would be seemless?

Comment: I was wondering that too... thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After finding out `RewriteMap` is disabled by my host, I've reached my own solution simply using `mod_rewrite` and 2x 301 redirects.

.htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^Product(.*)\.asp SEO_Redirect.php [NC,R=301]
```

SEO_Redirect.php file

```
$ID = $_GET['ID'];

$query_rsNewID = "SELECT NewProductID FROM Products WHERE OldProductID = '$ID'";
$rsNewID = mysql_query($query_rsNewID, $Database);
$row_rsNewID = mysql_fetch_assoc($rsNewID);

header ('HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently');
header ('Location: Product.php?ID='.$row_rsNewID['NewProductID']);
```

Note, this is a simplified excerpt of each file, and would not be secure against SQL injection.

Hopefully Google and alike will accept getting 2x 301 redirects without problems.

Comment: if you removed R=301 from your directive (e.g. [NC]) then it would still be a 2x redirect on the server, but the end user would only see a single redirect.

Answer (score 1):

Your query:

```
SELECT
  ID
FROM
  thetable
WHERE
  ProductID=?
```

From there just echo the value of `ID` and a newline, and flush stdout.

Rewrite rules:

```
RewriteMap dbfixup prg:dbfixup.script
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ProductID=(\d+)
RewriteRule Product.asp Products.php?ID=${dbfixup:%1}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. Where do i put the SQL query? Is it just in a php file (i.e. lookupscript.php), if so how does the ReWrite refer to it? - I'm unfamiliar with ReWriteMap.

Comment: The `prg` identifier in RewriteMap specifies that the following is a program to run in order to get the mapping. The program starts on httpd startup, and ends on httpd shutdown. The program receives the text to be mapped on stdin, and should output the map result on stdout and then flush. It should then loop back and wait for the next input. The "dbfixup.script" should be replaced with the program or script that will be executed in order to do the actual mapping.

Answer (score 0):

You should have a different get variable name for the new ID. That way in your new program you will know whether to match the product using the old ID or the new one.

```
$old = isset($_GET['id']) && is_numeric($_GET['id']) && $_GET['id'] > 0 ? $_GET['id'] : 0;
$new = isset($_GET['new']) && is_numeric($_GET['new']) && $_GET['new'] > 0 ? $_GET['new'] : 0;
if ($old + $new > 0) {
    $query = 'SELECT * FROM `ProductDetails` WHERE '.($old > 0 ? '`OrigPrdID`='.$old : '`PrdDetID`='.$new).' LIMIT 1;';
    ...
```