# Want to turn example.com/country/name/Korea to example.com/korea

Tags: zend-framework, .htaccess, url-routing, zend-route

I think the title explains it all. The thing is that my application is Zend Framework based and includes a number of controllers. The main controllers are:

```
Companies/
People/
Countries/
```

Initially a country profiles url could ve accessible via a url like:

```
example.com/countries/view/id/Korea
```

I shorted it by adding a router to

```
example.com/countries/Korea
```

However the client requires a further shortening to:

```
example.com/Korea
```

Bringing the name of the country which is in this case a url parameter in the place of the controller. Plus the clients requires that all the urls be shortened in a similar fashion so then a url for a company which used to read something like:

```
example.com/companies/acme-corporation-1234
```

where 1234 is the id of the company to read something on the lines of:

```
example.com/acme-corporation-company
```

I can understand uniqueness of country names as there aren't any two countries with similar names however I doubt I can accomplish the same for companies as you can have a number of companies with similar names. I checked out Gogobot.com and noticed that all of the urls on the site are really easy to read and don't even include a single id number anywhere.

Is there any idea on how this can be done i.e further shortened - so that example.com/korea doesn't mean Korea as a controller but as a link to example.com/countries/korea and likewise the url example.com/countries should still be interpreted as a call to countries controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please take a look at the similar problem one of the poster. You could use Apache's `RewriteMap` to map URL to external script and process the request based on the code.

That way, you don't have to worry about having a controller for each country, but pass it to the script to find the ID or anything that you want them to process.

[Mod_ReWrite / ReWriteMap a URL using a database lookup script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2130204/mod-rewrite-rewritemap-a-url-using-a-database-lookup-script/2130233#2130233)

Answer (score 0):

If you're reasonably comfortable with ZF you can use a custom route class for this, see this explanation: http://tfountain.co.uk/blog/2010/9/9/vanity-urls-zend-framework (slightly different problem there but the solution is the same). For your case you'll want one for companies and one for countries.