# .htaccess file rewrite id with String varient

Tags: php, .htaccess

Is it possible to rewrite a URL that looks like this as an example -

```
mydomain.com/?id=123
```

Lets pretend that `123` is an id of a row in a DB. a column in this row could be my name.
 I would like to rewrite this URL based on the result in the DB -

```
mydomain.com/rory
```

Is this possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there's a logic which can map an ID of 123 to a name "rory" why don't make a redirect like this one in PHP

```
$id = $_REQUEST['id'];

$name = getNameByIdFromDB($id);

header('Location: ' . $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"] . '/' . $name, 302);

exit;
```

(that's an example, not working code!)

Answer (score 1):

You  can use RewriteMap for that: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritemap

Have a look at the answers of the following question: [Mod_ReWrite / ReWriteMap a URL using a database lookup script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2130204/mod-rewrite-rewritemap-a-url-using-a-database-lookup-script)

Answer (score -1):

you cant touch dtb from .htaccess file,

you can manual render rules for all possible combinations, but its bad practise - this should be solved in router of your application

Comment: I realise that you cannot perform this in the .htaccess file. Are you unable to use server side code in conjunction with the rewrite?

Comment: i'm not sure what do you exactly mean with "server side code in conjunction with the rewrite"